# Boostrap Date picker Year range goes beyond?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have used bootstrap thai date picker. when i select my year range it show beyond.
[image]

the below image shows the year range from 2560-2569, but my date picker years starts from 2553.i duno where i went wrong.

```
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight:false
    });
```

can i know what option will make this to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your using the current version 1.6.4 as found at the following link

https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

And I didn't need to specify highlight today as false.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
endDate: "+0d",
autoclose: true,
startDate: '+543y' 
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Rob, It helped me alot, but i need to show those years as per buddhist year. that is current year + 543 and my date range also in buddhist year

Comment: if you look at the jsfiddle today date falls on saturday.. but it should fall on the today(i.e wednesday(19/04/2017)). can this can done using moment js locale ??

Comment: So you want to show today +543 years as well? I'm not sure how to do that without having to add code to the original GitHub Project :(